# Accessing audio/video metadata with .NET

Tags: .net, video, audio, mp3

What is the best way to get and set the meta data for mp3, mp4, avi files etc. with .NET?

Answer (score 6):

I use [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) with my C# apps, gives you a lot of information about media files.

Answer (score 4):

These are the example class files for different languages found in the MediaInfo.dll zip

- MediaInfoDLL.cs
- MediaInfoDLL.def
- MediaInfoDLL.h
- MediaInfoDLL.java
- MediaInfoDLL.jsl
- MediaInfoDLL.pas
- MediaInfoDLL.py
- MediaInfoDLL.vb
- MediaInfoDLL_Static.h

You do have to use interop and I don't know if you can edit tags, I've never needed to do that but it's pretty much a swiss army knife at least for getting media information from files.

[Link to downloads page (sourceforge)](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=86862&package_id=90614/showfiles.php?group_id=86862&package_id=90614)

MediaInfo_0.7.7.4_DLL_Win32.zip

Answer (score 3):

You can use free [UltraID3Lib](http://home.fuse.net/honnert/UltraID3Lib/) .NET library to read/write MP3 metadata.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking at the [NTag](http://web.archive.org/web/20140212092246/http://orthogonal.com.au/computers/ntag/index.htm) project as well, which handles MP3/WMA/OGG. I don't know of a single library that handles audio and video files, so you might have to use a few.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently used [Tag Lib Sharp](http://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp) to write some C# apps for cleaning up and maintaining my music library. I found the library very easy to use and although i've only used it for MP3's, it appears to support a range of other music/video formats.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like MediaInfo is read-only at this point, by the way: http://sourceforge.net/forum/message.php?msg_id=4241318&abmode=1

Very cool project, though. It's fun finding out about all this cool stuff here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I used COM interop to access [DirectShow's Media Detector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms785892(VS.85).aspx) functionality.

This does work pretty well, but it's a right pain in the backside. You need to know lots about COM, win32 interop, and so on.

You can also use [DirectShowNet](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html) which should handle most of that for you, I just didn't want to lug that whole thing around when I was only interested in the MediaDetector part