# how to get the duration from a mp4 media file by C#

Tags: c#, media

As I know a mp4 media file size, how could i calculate the file duration through file size? (C#)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) or which library you're implementing to work with the media file?

Comment: Depends on things such as the quality of the mp4 and how it is encoded

Comment: you have to know some media metadata look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091/accessing-audio-video-metadata-with-net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting MP4 File Duration with DirectShow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346136/getting-mp4-file-duration-with-directshow)

Answer (score 0):

Reading this: https://web.archive.org/web/20121130070329/http://neuron2.net/LVG/ratesandsizes.html I think perhaps you can approximately solve the number of seconds from the equation presented in the section **Calculating the File Size of a Bitrate-Based Format** using the metadata from the file.

Edit: URL changed as a suggestion by @BrentRittenhouse.

Comment: Hey Diego, that url no longer works. I don't know if editing your answer will make it look like _I_ did so I'm replying so you don't lose credit =) Here is an archive.org version of it that I found that looks lke the latest version that is the most complete. http://web.archive.org/web/20121130070329/http://neuron2.net/LVG/ratesandsizes.html

Answer (score 0):

Use ffmpeg command line and have it report your file properties.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at ID3 Metadata Tags in the file. You should use [TagLib Sharp](http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse11.1/taglib-sharp.html) for read ID3 tags from mp3/mp4 files.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [NReco.VideoInfo library](http://www.nrecosite.com/video_info_net.aspx) to achieve this very easily. It's a simple as giving the library a file path and it spits out the metadata:

```
var ffProbe = new FFProbe();
var videoInfo = ffProbe.GetMediaInfo(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
return videoInfo.Duration.TotalMilliseconds;
```