How do I change video description metadata fast in windows 10?
I have folders with 100s of videos and I need to change the meta data on these videos.
If I right click on one of the videos and go to properties and then details I can clear the meta data out of the title, comments, subtitle, tags, etc and hit apply and it clears the meta data within a split second.
Everywhere I look online or try to search for a solution keeps pointing to ffmpeg and other apps that have to recode the entire video without the metadata on it which is completely pointless in my opinion when windows can literally do it within a split second.
How do I automate the exact way windows explorer does it so that it takes a split second to change each video so I can do hundreds of them in just a few seconds or even a few minutes?
Using apps like ffmpeg and others it's taking minutes to do each video which is taking way too long and it seems way unnecessary.
Is there a way to do the same thing explorer is doing using maybe powershell, cmd, c# or something else?
if I have to wait minutes for each video to process to remove metadata I'm better of just right clicking each video and editing properties myself since it will end in the end be faster that way. Surely if exploror can do it so fast there has to be a way to access the same exe, dll, etc that windows is using and do it automatically fast just like hitting apply after changing it manually.
Any insight on how this could be done would be greatly appreciated. I'd like to just tell it a folder and have it search the folder and all subfolders for videos and remove the description metadata from the video files. title, subtitle, comment, tags, keywords, etc.
thanks anyone for your help and replies.
This is what I am trying to edit.


Could you clarify what sort of metadata you're trying to modify, and what types of files?  Do either of these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536464/editing-metadata-against-video-files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091/accessing-audio-video-metadata-with-net

@gunr2171 I edited the original message up top with an image of the info I'm trying to change. It's under description. I want to be able to delete anything that is in there or edit it which whatever info I want in there.

I'm unsure to understand what your screenshot is supposed to show. Are you trying to modify the framerate ?

@Pac0 really sorry about that I figured mentioning in the post saying I wanted to edit Description that was enough I didn't mean to click no frame rate when I screenshotted it. I fixed it with a new image.

hand-made circle is very clear now, thanks

I realize you'd prefer not to use other code, but I think you'll like exiftool. It is very fast, and you can easily use it with PowerShell.
https://exiftool.org
Using the "comments" field as an example. Choose others from the list for a given file format. You can check file-format-specific details, such as your ".mov" example from their main page: https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html
Shows the comments field:
.\exiftool.exe "C:\myMovie.mov" -json |  Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json | select comment

Sets the comments:
.\exiftool.exe  -"Comment"="HelloWorld" "C:\myMovie.mov"

Clears the comments:
.\exiftool.exe  -"Comment"= "C:\myMovie.mov"

